# Wifi inside a rocket

Tags: rf-power, wifi, microwave

I want to understand, as most rocket uses LAN cable and switches to communicate between stages. Is it possible to replace with WiFi? Although it's will be complex system but one idea to make each stages wireless. How can I improve reliability? With combination of wireless and wireless can we communicate within its structure. How to improve coupling between antennas?

Comment: Where did you read all rockets use LAN cable and switches?

Comment: Hello Shadid, Are you referring to [model hobby rockets](https://estesrockets.com/), or some other kind of rocket?

Comment: @shahidmobin Um, I'm no satellite engineer, but your claim seems pretty wrong.

Comment: You deleted your comment **"I am talking about a rocket which is used for taking the satellite to its orbit"**, and I suggest you edit your question with this new information.

Comment: See in Space SE: [Are and should satellites use wireless communication internally, rather than cables?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18512/12102) and also [Could multimode (polymer) optical fiber Gigabit Ethernet be a better choice than WiFi inside future satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19306/12102)

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue between stages is that wifi doesn't penetrate metal well.  Engine bells and plumbing are generally metal, even if tanks and exterior airframe skin aren't.  Since cables are highly reliable, it's worth having the weight to avoid dropouts when flight conditions add enough interference on top of the signal blockage to cut off your guidance at just the wrong time.

Too, signal wires needn't be heavy gauge; therefore, they can be fairly light (though the conduit they run in usually can't be lightened as much, it has to stand up to stresses of one kind or another).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can metal planes be avoided by using combination of both wired/wireless? suppose in interstage we can use antenna subsystem and using passive repeater we can avoid interstage penetration. although it is wired but advantage in interstates can become independent.

Comment: And now you have two separate comm systems inside a single vehicle.  Extra complexity, more points of failure, and probably aren't saving much if any weight over using wire everywhere.